# Align.so; symbol lookup error; undefined symbol

Tags: perl

I am running a perl script on a web server. I am getting the error in the httpd error log file:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: 
  /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Bio/Ext/Align/Align.so:
    undefined symbol:
      bp_sw_read_Blast_file_CompMat, referer: http://XX/model_select.pl
```

[Line breaks added for readability]

I checked some of the forums and did this:

```
cpanp -i /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Bio/Ext/Align/Align.so
ERROR '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Bio/Ext/Align/Align.so' does not contain an author part
ERROR Cannot find '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Bio/Ext/Align/Align.so' in the module tree
No such module: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Bio/Ext/Align/Align.so
No modules found to operate on!
Nothing done
```

I checked, `Align.so` exists in the path shown in the error message

Can someone please help me solve the problem. Thanks much ! :-)

Comment: The error message indicates you have a compiled module (XS module) where the C code calls a non-existing function. If reinstalling the newest version of the module doesn't help, consider asking the author of that module. However, the module does not seem to be on CPAN. Maybe it is an internal module at your institution. We can't help with that.

Comment: The first error probably means the `perl` that installed Bio::Ext::Align is different than the `perl` that's trying to load it. Reinstalling Bio::Ext::Align might do the trick. Or maybe you are telling `perl` to look in the wrong location for modules (e.g. via env var `PERL5LIB`).

Comment: The second error is because `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Bio/Ext/Align/Align.so` is not the name of a module or distribution.

Comment: I have an update on this - I tried to see what could be the problem. In the process I figured out some issue like this; I use five perl modules in the script namely; Bio::Tools::pSW, Bio::Seq, Bio::SimpleAlign, Bio::AlignIO, Bio::Ext::Align. In the script when I remove the module "Bio::Ext::Align", I still get the same error above. I did this step for all modules to see which module could be the cause of problem, and found out that when I remove "Bio::Tools::pSW", I get to the part of script just before this module. Could this module be the problem? Please let me know what you think? Thanks!